# How can fixed this error in moodle update?

Tags: moodle

HelloW!

When I went to upgrade moodle 3.10 to 3.11 and later 4.x.

I got a problem, after installing all the plugins that weren't on disk, and others that weren't found.

When proceeding, I had this image error.

[Error Image Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQvG3.jpg)

I use moodle in PT-BR, this is an error log:

```
Atualizando para nova versão
Importação de idioma: pt_br_old
Impossível achar componente

Outras informações sobre este erro

Informações de depuração:  pt_br_old
Error code: cannotfindcomponent×Ignorar essa notificação
Rastreamento de pilha: 
line 810 of /lib/componentlib.class.php: lang_installer_exception thrown
line 665 of /lib/componentlib.class.php: call to lang_installer->install_language_pack()
line 45 of /admin/tool/langimport/lib.php: call to lang_installer->run()
line 1741 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to tool_langimport_preupgrade_update()
line 1856 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_language_pack()
line 519 of /admin/index.php: call to upgrade_core()
```

**log in english:**

```
Updating to new version
Language import: pt_br_old
Impossible to find component

Other information about this error

Debug info: pt_br_old
Error code: cannotfindcomponent×Ignore this notification
Stack tracking:
line 810 of /lib/componentlib.class.php: lang_installer_exception thrown
line 665 of /lib/componentlib.class.php: call to lang_installer->install_language_pack()
line 45 of /admin/tool/langimport/lib.php: call to lang_installer->run()
line 1741 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to tool_langimport_preupgrade_update()
line 1856 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_language_pack()
line 519 of /admin/index.php: call to upgrade_core()
```

I installed all the missing plugins on the disk given in the update.

I downloaded and installed the PT-BR Moodle 3.11 language pack in the lang folder and also cleared the cache of the folders inside moodledata in my case it has another name. But i don't delete lang folder in moodledata and exist content in this folder.
path moodledata: /var/AnotherName

I updated the system, ubuntu, entered the permissions in the folder again and nothing worked until now.

I kept the config.php from the old moodle as recommended. The only warning I got in the update was about input_vars below 5000, and about the database not being in exact moodle format. But it was just warnings.

Comment: An update to 4.1+ and this error don't more for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your function xmldb_plugin_name_upgrade($oldversion) you have a final line that returns a true value.

That is: return true at the end of the function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).